# Wrong URL when parsing HTML with Jsoup Android

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

could you help me with parsing html site?
I need get src of image and link to another page, but I don't know why I get empty list
This is my code:

```
Elements elems2 = doc.select("div");
for (Element elem2 : elems2) {
    if (elem2.attr("class").equals("grid-box-img")) {
        System.out.println(elem2.attr("img"));
        kfunewphoto.add(elem2.attr("src"));
    }
}
```

and example of html:

```
<div class="grid-box-img"><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/shou-talanty-uspej-uvidet-pervym/" rel="bookmark" title="Шоу &#8220;Таланты&#8221;. Успей увидеть первым!"><img width="680" height="470" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7PGK.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="shou-talanty-uspej-uvidet-pervym-clever-russia" /></a></div>
```

I need get "http://cleverrussia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/shou-talanty-uspej-uvidet-pervym-clever-russia.png" and the second part of code:

```
            Elements elems = doc.select("h2");
            for (Element elem : elems) {
                if (elem.attr("class").equals("entry-title")) {
                    str = elem.text();
                    kfunews.add(elem.text());
                    kfunewslist1.add(elem.attr("href"));
                }

<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://cleverrussia.com/shou-talanty-uspej-uvidet-pervym/" title="Permalink to Шоу &#8220;Таланты&#8221;. Успей увидеть первым!" rel="bookmark">Шоу &#8220;Таланты&#8221;. Успей увидеть первым!</a></h2>
```

And I need get: "http://cleverrussia.com/shou-talanty-uspej-uvidet-pervym/" 
This is full code of page - view-source:http://cleverrussia.com/

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you're trying to select img and a as attributes. Check the below code to see how to fix your code.

```
// Prints the image source
System.out.println(elem2.select("img").attr("src"));
kfunewphoto.add(elem2.select("img").attr("src"));
// Prints the target link
System.out.println(elem.select("a").attr("href"));
kfunewslist1.add(elem.select("a").attr("href"));
```